# Validation not bubbling up to my other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, polymorphism, event-bubbling

Ok, I have a relationship between People, Users and Employees such that All Employees are Users and all Users are People. `Person` is an abstract class that `User` is derived from and `Employee` is derived from that.

Now... I have an `EmployeesController` class and the `create` method looks like this:

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
  @employee.user = User.new(params[:user])
  @employee.user.person = Person.new(params[:person])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @employee.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Employee was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@employee) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @employee, :status => :created, :location => @employee }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @employee.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, when I'm using the `:polymorphic => true` clause, the way you access the super class is by doing something like `@derived_class_variable.super_class_variable.super_super_etc`. The `Person` class has a `validates_presence_of :first_name` and when it is satisfied, on my form, everything is OK. However, if I leave out the first name, it won't prevent the employee from being saved. What happens is that the employee record is saved but the person record isn't (because of the validation).

How can I get the validation errors to show up in the flash object?

Comment: Is this really the way polymorphism is done in Ruby? 'cause in all of the other languages I know, the class ctors themselves pass the subset of parameters on to the subclasses at creation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was `validates_associated` so i would have:

employee.rb

```
validates_associated :user
```

user.rb

```
validates_associated :person
```